# Why is Unit in PureScript's Prelude {} in JavaScript?

Tags: purescript

I'm a beginner to FP and Type-level programming.
I learned `Void` and `Unit` recently.

Prelude's `unit` is defined as `{}` in JavaScript.

```js
"use strict";

exports.unit = {};
```

My question is "Why not `null` but `{}`?"
Maybe this is a trivial question, but I'd like to learn its philosophy.

From my understanding, `unit` corresponds to `null` in JavaScript.
For example, I can call a function with no arguments in JavaScript.

```js
// hello :: Void -> String
function hello () {
  return "hello"
}

const h1 = hello() // "hello"
// However, I do not have any members of `Void` in PureScript, so I cannot call like above.
```

If I have to specify some arguments of `hello` function, I choose `null` rather than `{}`.

```js
// hello :: forall a. a -> String
function hello (a) {
  return "hello"
}

// 'hello :: Unit -> String'-like
const h1 = hello(null) // "hello"

// undefined also works, but weird to me
const h2 = hello(undefined)

// also works, but weird
const h3 = hello(42)
const h4 = hello({})
const h5 = hello([])
```

If `unit` represents a side-effect, probably is it `undefined` or something `null`?

```js
// 'log1 :: String -> Effect Void'-like
function log1 (s) {
  return s => () => console.log(s) // console.log return undefined
}
// however, function must return a value


// 'log2 :: String -> Effect Unit'-like
function log2 (s) {
  return s => () => {
    console.log(s) // side-effect
    return null
  }
}

// foreign Effect.Console.log (ECMAScript-style)
function log3 (s) {
  return s => () => {
    console.log(s)
    return {} // weird to me; it seems like 'return 42'
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't actually matter what value you use for `Unit`. `{}` is a pretty arbitrary choice - `undefined` or `null`, or just not returning a value are all fine too if you're writing something in the FFI. Since `Unit` is only supposed to have one inhabitant, there's never a time that the actual runtime value for it is examined.

It's quite a long time since the choice of `{}` was made - it's probably a historical accident, leftover from the time that all non-`Prim` PS values were constructed as anonymous objects.

Comment: I would also add that `function hello() { return "hello" }` is NOT equivalent to `Void -> String`, but equivalent to `Unit -> String`. And similarly there is no such thing as `Effect Void`.